# Get data-attributes with jQuery .class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick, click

I want to trigger an onClick event for an entire class of elements. Normally, I would do something like this:

```
$(".classy").click(function(){
    console.log("Replace this line with something useful!");
});
```

However, every element of this class has distinct data-attributes that I want to use inside the onClick function. For example:

```
<div className="classy" data-num={100}></div>
<div className="classy" data-num={931}></div>
<div className="classy" data-num={777}></div>
```

On the click of each element, I would want to log the `data-num` value. Is there any way to do this with jQuery's `.click`?

Comment: so what you want is the `data-num` of the `div` you click right.?

Comment: Just do `this.dataset.num` inside the event handler

Comment: The selector matches multiple elements, but the events don't get bound to the set as a whole, but to each individual element in that set. So triggering the event on one of those elements will not trigger the events on the other elements. Inside the function you will have one element that triggered the event, which is `this`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/Lk0pnu8e/

```js
$(".classy").click(function(){
    console.log("First Way: " + $(this).attr('data-num'));
    console.log("Second Way: " + $(this).data('num'));
    console.log("Replace this line with something useful!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classy" data-num={100}>100</div>
<div class="classy" data-num={931}>931</div>
<div class="classy" data-num={777}>777</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine for you -

```
$('body').on('click','.classy',function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('data-num'));
});
```

Am using the body so that even you add the div using AJAX(dynamically) the `click` will work.